# I'd like to know how to change colors if the number is 50 in the ul class with jQuery, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to make a reservation when the number next to title is greater than 50.
code is like this:

```
<ul class="preview-list">
  <li>
    <a><span>class</span>title1</a>
    <span class="icon-image">this is icon</span>
    <span class="badge-reply">156</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><span>class</span>title2</a>
    <span class="badge-reply">30</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Results when running this source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrP1u.png)

These ul classes have multiple copies within this web page.All the classes are equal.

How can I change the color to red when the numver over 50?

Comment: @DivyaMamgai Not sure why that's relevant here - that can happen on any web page

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, but I think the OP should realize this and use pure JavaScript logic to store the values and act upon those and not the content of the html tags which is dangerous. Maybe they can use MVC model to their benefit here.

Comment: @DivyaMamgai going by that logic you should also warn the OP that a user can load his own css and JavaScript onto his web page useing plugins. Which also can spoof his logic.

Comment: MaseKor you said:- `I'd like to make a reservation when the number next to title is greater than 50`.So you need to check number of `title1,title2,.....` isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following script for this

```js
$('.badge-reply').each(function(){
  if(parseInt($(this).html()) > 50) {
    $(this).css('color','red');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="preview-list">
  <li>
    <a><span>class</span>title1</a>
    <span class="icon-image">this is icon</span>
    <span class="badge-reply">156</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><span>class</span>title2</a>
    <span class="badge-reply">30</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Or you can use**

```js
$('.badge-reply').filter(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).html()) > 50;
}).css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="preview-list">
  <li>
    <a><span>class</span>title1</a>
    <span class="icon-image">this is icon</span>
    <span class="badge-reply">156</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><span>class</span>title2</a>
    <span class="badge-reply">30</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Using Javascript**

```js
var mainDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("badge-reply");

for(var i=0;i<mainDiv.length;i++) {
   if(mainDiv[i].innerHTML > 50) {
    mainDiv[i].style.color = "#ff0000";
   }
}
```

```html
<ul class="preview-list">
  <li>
    <a><span>class</span>title1</a>
    <span class="icon-image">this is icon</span>
    <span class="badge-reply">156</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><span>class</span>title2</a>
    <span class="badge-reply">30</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to settle down to java script without jquery?

Comment: @MaseKor  you said `make a reservation when the number next to title is greater than 50` ? then from where `badge-reply` come into picture? you need to check `title1,title2.....`? don't you

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use `filter()` to find the elements where the text is above 50, then add a class to them. The important part of the logic is the conversion of the string to a number using `parseInt()`. Try this:

```js
$('.badge-reply').filter(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).text(), 10) > 50;
}).addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="preview-list">
  <li>
    <a><span>class</span>title1</a>
    <span class="icon-image">this is icon</span>
    <span class="badge-reply">156</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><span>class</span>title2</a>
    <span class="badge-reply">30</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: OP says `reservation when the number next to title is greater than 50`. then why every-one doing through  `badge-reply`?

Answer (score 0):

Simple with css, u no need javascript for that
Use that and change nth-child(n+2) to nth-child(n+50)

```css
ul.preview-list li:nth-child(n+2){
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="preview-list">
  <li>
    <a><span>class</span>title1</a>
    <span class="icon-image">this is icon</span>
    <span class="badge-reply">156</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><span>class</span>title2</a>
    <span class="badge-reply">30</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a><span>class</span>title2</a>
    <span class="badge-reply">30</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ul class="preview-list">
       <li>
         <a><span>class</span><span class="something">title1</span></a>
         <span class="icon-image">this is icon</span>
         <span class="badge-reply">156</span>
       </li>
       <li>
         <a><span>class</span><span class="something">title2</span></a>
         <span class="badge-reply">30</span>
       </li>
     </ul>
```

here is the jquery code

```
 $('.somthing').each(function(){
 var tn = $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''); // Replace everything that is not a number with nothing
      if(parseInt(tn) > 50) { // Check if it is more than 50 then color red

        $(this).css('color','red');
      }
    });
```